# Does the signed url cache on Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

I want to use a signed url.

If I use this url structure, can I also use the cache system?

I want to avoid spending too much traffic from the same files.

Comment: Can I ask what exactly you mean cache system? Why at all do you think it won't work? are there any problems with implementation?

Comment: @vitooh As I understand it;
When we use the signed url, the url will turn into something like this

storagelink.com/storagepath/content.webm?signedurl = ...

and I think direct entries like storagelink.com/storagepath/content.webm will be blocked.

I think it may cause cache problems because the query strings is different.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this is not possible. According to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#caching_data) cache-control applies to "publicatly accessible" objects. Which if I understand correctly means that they have to be allowed to `allUsers`.

On the other side accoriding to [Signed URL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#overview):

> When you generate a signed URL, you specify a user or service account
>   which must have sufficient permission to make the request that the
>   signed URL will make

As I understand this means that it's not allowed to `allUsers` and you cannot use cache.

I hope this theoretical thinking will help you somehow :)